# Inequality sine power series

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, induction, taylor-expansion

How can we show, for $k\geq 1$ and $x \geq 0$, the inequality below by induction?

$\displaystyle \sin x \geq \sum_{n=1}^{2k} (-1)^{n+1} \frac 1{ (2n - 1)! }x^{2n-1} $

The base case $k = 1$ gives $\sin x \geq x - \frac 16 x^3$ which is true (verification/proof excluded). Now, let's assume for $k = p$ that

$\displaystyle \sin x \geq \sum_{n=1}^{2p} (-1)^{n+1} \frac 1{ (2n - 1)! }x^{2n-1} $

We wish now to show that it holds true for $k = p +1$ i.e.

$\displaystyle \sin x \geq \sum_{n=1}^{2(p+1)} (-1)^{n+1} \frac 1{ (2n - 1)! }x^{2n-1} $

For the sum on the right-hand sive above, we can write

$ \sum_{n=1}^{2p+2} (-1)^{n+1} \frac 1{ (2n - 1)! }x^{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^{2p}\left(  (-1)^{n+1} \frac 1{ (2n - 1)! }x^{2n-1} \right) + \frac 1{ (4p+1)! }x^{4p} - \frac 1{ (4p+3)! }x^{4p+2} $

By assumption, we have

$ \sum_{n=1}^{2p}\left(  (-1)^{n+1} \frac 1{ (2n - 1)! }x^{2n-1} \right) + \frac 1{ (4p+1)! }x^{4p} - \frac 1{ (4p+3)! }x^{4p+2} \leq \sin x + \frac 1{ (4p+1)! }x^{4p} - \frac 1{ (4p+3)! }x^{4p+2} $

This is where I do not see how to progress. If we somehow could make the two terms besides $\sin x$ vanish we would have our desired inequality but I do not see what one could do. Any tips?

EDIT: Just realised that we can write

$ \displaystyle \sin x + \frac 1{ (4p+1)! }x^{4p} - \frac 1{ (4p+3)! }x^{4p+2} \leq \sin x + \frac 1{ (4p+1)! }x^{4p}  $

Only one last term remaining to rid of. Any idea?

Comment: Anyone? Got any thoughts? Help much appreciated

Comment: When you took out your two terms for n=2p+1 and n=2p+2, the exponents on the x should match the values in the denominator, should they not? $\frac 1{ (4p+1)! }x^{4p+1}$ rather then the exponent of 4p that you have. Likewise it should be $x^{4p+3}$ in the next term